# find a polar equation

Tags: parametric

$xy=7$

we get:

$r(\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))=7$

therefore the only logical equation that could possibly arise is:

$r=\frac{7}{\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}$

yet web assign said nope $#%& off. Am I missing something basic here or is web assign dead wrong?

Comment: If $x = r \cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$, then $x y = r \cos \theta \cdot r \sin \theta = r^2 \cos \theta \sin \theta$.

Answer (score 1):

$$xy=r\cos\theta r\sin \theta$$
$$r^2=\frac{7}{\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}$$
$$r^2=\frac{7}{\sin(2\theta)/2}$$
$$r^2=14\csc 2\theta$$